# Test arbitrary code containing Arrays with uTest

Tags: scala, utest

uTest has a hack in `utest.asserts.Asserts` to compare two Arrays with the `==>` comparator. But how can I compare Arrays in arbitrary code?

Update with more precise question:
What is the easiest way to test arbitrary code containing Arrays with uTest?

Comment: Or, hear me out, don't use `Arrays` unless you have a strong reason for using them.

Comment: I have a strong reason

Comment: What is your strong reason? Because if it is performance, you just throw it out by using this convoluted comparison.

Comment: I need to test code from a library that returns Arrays (using another library is not an option). It's not for performance. If you have a better way of doing this, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I would try to write a **Scala** _facade_ over such library and convert the `Arrays` to a proper **Scala** collection as soon as possible and preserve typesafety. But I lack enough context to give proper advice about how to do that. Anyways, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply your own `==>` comparator that checks arbitrary code where Arrays have been substituted with Lists. Let your test class extend a trait like this when you have tests involving Arrays:

```scala
trait Array2List {

  // Allow comparing Arrays

  implicit class ArrowAssert(lhs: Any) {
    def ==>[V](rhs: V): Unit = {
      val (left, right) = (r(lhs), r(rhs))
      Predef.assert(
        left == right,
        s"""(Arrays converted to Lists)
           |Got     : $left
           |Expected: $right
           |""".stripMargin
      )
    }
  }

  // Recursively convert Arrays to Lists
  private def r(code: Any): Any = code match {
    case arr: Array[_]  => arr.toList // or recurse here too...
    case opt: Option[_] => opt.map(r)
    case seq: Seq[_]    => seq.map(r)
    case set: Set[_]    => set.map(r)
    case map: Map[_, _] => map.map { case (k, v) => (k, r(v)) }
    case tpl: Product   => tpl match {
      case Tuple1(a)                                                                 => Tuple1(a)
      case Tuple2(a, b)                                                              => Tuple2(r(a), r(b))
      case Tuple3(a, b, c)                                                           => Tuple3(r(a), r(b), r(c))
      case Tuple4(a, b, c, d)                                                        => Tuple4(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d))
      case Tuple5(a, b, c, d, e)                                                     => Tuple5(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e))
      case Tuple6(a, b, c, d, e, f)                                                  => Tuple6(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f))
      case Tuple7(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)                                               => Tuple7(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g))
      case Tuple8(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)                                            => Tuple8(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h))
      case Tuple9(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)                                         => Tuple9(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i))
      case Tuple10(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)                                     => Tuple10(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j))
      case Tuple11(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k)                                  => Tuple11(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k))
      case Tuple12(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l)                               => Tuple12(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l))
      case Tuple13(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m)                            => Tuple13(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l), r(m))
      case Tuple14(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n)                         => Tuple14(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l), r(m), r(n))
      case Tuple15(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o)                      => Tuple15(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l), r(m), r(n), r(o))
      case Tuple16(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p)                   => Tuple16(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l), r(m), r(n), r(o), r(p))
      case Tuple17(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q)                => Tuple17(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l), r(m), r(n), r(o), r(p), r(q))
      case Tuple18(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, w)             => Tuple18(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l), r(m), r(n), r(o), r(p), r(q), r(w))
      case Tuple19(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, w, s)          => Tuple19(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l), r(m), r(n), r(o), r(p), r(q), r(w), r(s))
      case Tuple20(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, w, s, t)       => Tuple20(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l), r(m), r(n), r(o), r(p), r(q), r(w), r(s), r(t))
      case Tuple21(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, w, s, t, u)    => Tuple21(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l), r(m), r(n), r(o), r(p), r(q), r(w), r(s), r(t), r(u))
      case Tuple22(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, w, s, t, u, v) => Tuple22(r(a), r(b), r(c), r(d), r(e), r(f), r(g), r(h), r(i), r(j), r(k), r(l), r(m), r(n), r(o), r(p), r(q), r(w), r(s), r(t), r(u), r(v))
      case bigger                                                                    => bigger // Scala 3
    }
    // possibly more transformations to match the data types of your test code...
    case value          => value
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not converting the array _"Recursively"_ BTW.

Comment: I'm recursing the arbitrary code to find Arrays to be converted to Lists. Not the Arrays themselves since for my use case that is not needed. But you could recurse into them too if needed. This is a solution open for modifications not a "This is the way".

Answer (score 1):

This example is one-liner that works, but involves creating a duplicate data structure.

```
def isMatch[A](array1 :Array[A], array2 :Array[A]) :Boolean =
    (array1.length == array2.length) && array1.zip(array2).forall { case (x,y) => x == y }
```

This example uses an `Int` to compare each element in place so is more effecient and follows Scala's functional immutable approach by prefering recursion over a for-loop

```
def isMatch[A](array1 :Array[A], array2 :Array[A]) :Boolean = {

    @annotation.tailrec
    def checkElement(i :Int) :Boolean = (i == array1.length) match {
        case true => true
        case false if array1(i) == array2(i) => checkElement(i+1)
        case false => false
    }
    
    array1.length == array2.length && checkElement(0)
}
```

And this is a classic for-loop implementation:

```
def isMatch[A](array1 :Array[A], array2 :Array[A]) :Boolean = {

    (array1.length == array2.length) match {
        case false => false
        case true =>

        var i :Int = 0
        
        while (i < array1.length && array1(i) == array2(i))
          i += 1
        
        // did comparison get to the end without failing?
        (i == array1.length)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was not entirely clear from my question that I wanted a solution on how to allow using Arrays _with uTest_. So I updated the question accordingly.